# How to concatenate fields in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have this simple table.

```
City            Country   State      Id
Great Falls      (null)   VA         12345
Great Falls      USA      VA         12345
```

I wanted to use CONCAT function for City + Country + State with running code below in Oracle environment.

```
SELECT City, Country, State, 
City ||', ' ||Country|| ', '||State AS Concat_fields
FROM #TEMP

City    Country    State       Concat_fields           Id
Great Falls (null) VA          Great Falls, , VA       12345
Great Falls USA    VA          Great Falls, USA, VA    12345
```

Question: is there a better that the query can altered in such a way that it returns only 1 record? I wanted to show my result like this:

```
City        Country State   Concat_fields           Id
Great Falls USA     VA       Great Falls, USA, VA   12345
```

Any thoughts, criticisms, suggestions?

Comment: search for LISTAGG

Comment: Thanks. Marmite. I tried something like this...LISTAGG(City ||', ' ||Country|| ', '||State) AS TEST. the query still returns two rows.

Comment: How do you decide when and how to pick one of the records, or merge them, or whatever? What would you do if the rows (for an ID, presumably) had different values, rather than just a missing values?

Comment: @Alex, Thanks for your feed. I don't have the answer yet. I am trying to return the desired result. There are many possibilities. thanks.

Comment: It seems you just want to dismiss records where the country is null: `select … where country is not null`. If this is not it, what is it then? Alex is right: First make up your mind what to select, only then write the query. It seems you have written the query before thinking it through. We cannot help much here. You must decide for rules what to select.

Comment: Will Do. thanks for all your feed back, suggestions and answers. Much appreciate all

Comment: You might also consider - I've had clients who wanted `null` countries to be treated as 'USA'. In this case you could do `nvl(country,'USA')` and do a `select distinct`.

Comment: I got an idea - just maybe it could work. Use the LISTAGG for each separate query. like LISTAGG for City, LISTAGG for Country, and LISTAGG for State. Then treat these w queries as separate tables. do a final LISTAGG separated by a semi column (;)? Testing now

Answer (score 2):

If the only difference between the rows are null vs. non-null values, then you can use an aggregate before concatenating:

```
-- CTE for sample data
with "#TEMP" (city, country, state, id) as (
  select 'Great Falls', null, 'VA', 12345 from dual
  union all select 'Great Falls', 'USA', 'VA', 12345 from dual
)
-- actual query
select max(city) as city, max(country) as country, max(state) as state, 
  max(city) ||', ' ||max(country)|| ', '||max(state) as concat_fields
from "#TEMP"
group by id;

CITY        COU ST CONCAT_FIELDS       
----------- --- -- --------------------
Great Falls USA VA Great Falls, USA, VA
```

If the rows for an ID have different non-null values then that obviously won't work:

```
with "#TEMP" (city, country, state, id) as (
  select 'Great Falls', null, 'VA', 12345 from dual
  union all select 'London', 'UK', null, 12345 from dual
)
select max(city) as city, max(country) as country, max(state) as state, 
  max(city) ||', ' ||max(country)|| ', '||max(state) as concat_fields
from "#TEMP";

CITY        CO ST CONCAT_FIELDS      
----------- -- -- -------------------
London      UK VA London, UK, VA
```

but then you would need some way to determine which row is correct - e.g. from a sequence or date column if this represents a history of addresses for a customer and you want the 'latest' version. The trick then is knowing how to determine which is 'latest'.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT City, Country, State, 
City ||', ' ||Country|| ', '||State AS Concat_fields
FROM #TEMP
WHERE Country IS NOT NULL
```

This will work for the provided dataset.

Generally speaking though Ids are unique (primary key), so make sure you are building your table in a way that adheres to more accepted database practices.